# I want to remove Ubuntu and reinstall Windows XP from CD

Tags: installation, boot-failure, windows-xp, format

Ubuntu is working on the PC but I want to sell the PC with original Windows XP Professional Edition. I cannot boot the CD. Rebooting  and selecting "*Start from CD*" always starts the installed Ubuntu. I wish to format the hard disk and do a clean Windows XP installation to sell it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you re-booting PC, and stopping at BIOS with (typically) F9 to choose boot device?  Does it work if you choose CD-drive, at that point?

Answer (score 2):

Put the xp cd.

Open BIOS by pressing F12 or Del (As per your motherboard, see the corners of flashing screen just after starting the computer)

There will be a menu as `Boot` and inside that there should be boot priority. Set the dvd/cd driver as first option.

Save and exit.

If it doesn't boot probably the disk is damaged.

Comment: you're missing this step: set fire to the xp disc get windows 7 basic, put the w7 dvd isntall it, better than xp and it's newer.